ASP.NET Core DropDownList with groups
I have a drop down list that has the following items.
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 1" } },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 1" } },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 2" } },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 3" } },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 5", Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 4" } },
        };

In the view is rendered via
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, items)

When it displays however it renders like this

with the groups on every line. I tried adding the group to only the first option, but it ungrouped the subsequent rows.

You could try this below code:
HomeController.cs:
using DropDownListDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DropDownListDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var group1 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 1" };
            var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 2" };
            var group3 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 3" };
            var group4 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 4" };

            var model = new DropdownViewModel
            {
                Options = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Value = "1", Group = group1 },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Value = "2", Group = group1 },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Value = "3", Group = group2 },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Value = "4", Group = group3 },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 5", Value = "5", Group = group4 }
                }
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(DropdownViewModel model)
        {
            // Handle form submission
            var selectedValue = model.SelectedOption;

            // Do something with the selected value

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}

Index.cshtml:
@model DropDownListDemo.Models.DropdownViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h2>Select an Option</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <select asp-for="SelectedOption" asp-items="Model.Options" class="form-control"></select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


Or for Asp.net you could try this:
DropdownViewModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace DropdownListExample.Models
{
    public class DropdownViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
    }
}

HomeController:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DropdownListExample.Models;


namespace DropdownListExample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var group1 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 1" };
            var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 2" };
            var group3 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 3" };
            var group4 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 4" };

            var list = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Group = group1 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Group = group1 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Group = group2 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Group = group3 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 5", Group = group4 },
            };

            var model = new DropdownViewModel
            {
                Options = list
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(DropdownViewModel model)
        {
            // Handle form submission and process selected option
            ViewBag.Message = $"You selected: {model.SelectedOption}";
            model.Options = GetOptions(); // Reassign options to avoid null reference
            return View(model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOptions()
        {
            var group1 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 1" };
            var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 2" };
            var group3 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 3" };
            var group4 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Group 4" };

            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Group = group1 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Group = group1 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Group = group2 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Group = group3 },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 5", Group = group4 },
            };
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml:
@model DropdownListExample.Models.DropdownViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>Select an Option</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOption, Model.Options, "Select an option", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}

@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}



What does your view look like?

@Craig updated code

Unfortunately doesn't work for me, same result.

@Craig could you share your updated reproducible code with us that would be great

@Craig also added code for asp.net mvc
